# "There has been an error cropping your image" when cropping image

Tags: images, cropping, header-image

I am setting the header image in WordPress and when I click on the `crop` button, it shows me the following error:

`There has been an error cropping your image.`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is too little information to be completely sure, but usually this error occurs when WordPress cannot find the graphic library which should be installed on your server. So you should check with your provider to see if [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) and/or [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) are installed.

You can also add this little snippet of code in your `functions.php` file to make sure WordPress looks for both (often it only looks for Imagick):

```
add_filter ('wp_image_editors', 'wpse303391_change_graphic_editor');
function wpse303391_change_graphic_editor ($array) {
    return array( 'WP_Image_Editor_GD', 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick' );
    }
```

This snippet will look for GD first and then for Imagick. The latter gives better quality, but uses more memory, which can also lead to server errors.

Comment: Is there a list of these "extra" requirements anywhere? https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/ doesn't mention any PHP libraries that need to be installed.

Comment: Wordpress assumes there is a complete PHP install on the server. It's not something "extra".

Comment: You're a life saver thank you, GoDaddy said it was installed but was still throwing the error. This fixed it

Answer (score 3):

I solved this installing the next library

sudo apt-get install php5-gd -> for php5

sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd -> for php7

sudo apt-get install php7.2-gd -> for php7.2

Comment: Didn't even have to refresh the page after install. Thanks

Comment: On CentOS it's `yum install php-gd`, for the interested.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same issue and unable to understand how to resolve this issue by following given ideas on every portals as I am not hardcore programmer so it was not possible for me to understand their tricks but Now I have successfully troubleshooted this image cropping issue and am sharing my trick how it was troubleshooted.

You just have to open your xampp controller and stop both the services Apache and MySQL and now click on congfig button of Apache and select PHP(PHP.ini), After selecting you will see a config file, find

```
;extension=gd
```

text, Now just remove ; to enable gd services at your system for PHP as by default it comes with commented and save the file and restart both services Apache and MySQL.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: This one works. Just remember to refresh the page before trying to crop again.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered the same issue with my blog, after searching for a while found out that it was because [GD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GD_Graphics_Library) library for [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) which was not installed on the server

Since my server is hosted on CentOS, to find the GD Library package within CentOS repository

```
$ sudo yum list available | grep 'gd'
```

Identify GD Library package name and install it

```
$ sudo yum install php-gd
```

Restart apache service

```
$ sudo service httpd restart
```

A detailed article that I wrote can be found [here](https://rohutech.com/there-has-been-an-error-cropping-your-image/) with command output screenshots

Comment: You appear to be the author of the linked article. When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.